# UWP App installation

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I try to install my UWP-APP on a windows tablet with this code in command prompt:

> WinAppDeployCmd install -file "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX_1.0.0.0_x86.appx" -ip 192.168.2.104

But I become this failures:

> 0x80131500 - Beim Aufruf einer COM-Komponente wurde ein HRESULT E_FAIL-Fehler zurückgegeben.
>
> 0x80004005 - Beim Aufruf einer COM-Komponente wurde ein HRESULT
>   E_FAIL-Fehler zurückgegeben.

Can u tell me the errors or give me a list where I can read them?

Sorry the exceptions are in german....

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of Windows 10 on your tablet? Because I remember old versions had a known issue regarding this.

Besides, can you install apps using the default app installer by double clicking on the appx file (of course you should move your app to the tablet in this case)?

And double check that your tablet's 'Device Discovery' and 'Device Portal' are turned on (in For Developers settings) and check if there is a password set, you should consider that in your syntax:

WinAppDeployCmd install /path/ -ip /ip/ -pin /pin/